# Generate pdf file with Itext PDF and Freemarker : blank image using base64

Tags: java, itext, freemarker

I've been looking for the solution to why the image doesn't show up using the base64 encoded string in the pdf file.
I have Java class to generate pdf reports with itextpdf and Freemarker template. there is a logo image that I want to pass on to the report. the logo value using base64 encoded string with the format as following:

```
data:image/jpg;base64,base64EncodedString
```

here is the Freemarker template:

```
  <#macro header logo>
  <header>
    <table width="800">
      <tr>
          <#if logo??>
            <td width="300"> 
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/08/20/03/flag-1244649_960_720.jpg" width="60" height="60" align="left"/>
              <img src="${logo}" width="60" height="60" align="left"/>
            </td>
          </#if>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
  </header>

</#macro>
```

the first image using URL path is working, however the second image using base64 is blank.
the image appears when I run it through jsfiddle or using html file
https://jsfiddle.net/riskiana/jvug1tzL/3/

please somebody help me.

thanks

Comment: hi @KJ the image size is only 77KB, and the base64EncodedString length is 135127 characters. does it mean there is a limitation on the length that can be injected into PDF that causing the problem?

Comment: unfortunately, I'm still not able to display the image even though it's using  data:image/jpeg

Comment: hi @KJ thanks for help, your sample  image is working fine here if I open directly the html file. however if I copy the script into my freemarker file , the image still blanks. thats also happens to my image. it works if I open directly using html file.

Comment: I'm wondering if this related  to base64 encoded string incompatibility  of spring boot and itext pdf library that I use

Answer (score 0):

iText html2pdf currently doesn't support base 64 encoded resources.